# Magento 2.1 - Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64$d filterable and/or sortable attributes

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm getting the error below during my re-index:

> The Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64$d filterable and/or sortable
>   attributes.Currently there are 92$d of them.Please reduce the number
>   of filterable/sortable attributes in order to use this module

How can I fix it? Is that a limit in MYSQL?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's limitation of  mysql: A table can contain a maximum of 64 secondary indexes.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Simple solution is not use flat indexex.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the default config value, that is currently used, in your own module. Create `\Namespace\Module\etc\config.xml` and put following into it

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>            
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <flat>
                    <max_index_count>128</max_index_count>
                </flat>
            </product>
        </catalog>
    </default>
</config>
```