# Magento 2.3.5 - Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64$d filterable and/or sortable attributes

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, attributes

I'm getting the error below during my setup:upgrade:

> The Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64$d filterable and/or sortable
> attributes. Currently, there are 67$d of them. Please reduce the number
> of filterable/sortable attributes in order to use this module

Also, I had referred the LINK: [Magento 2.1 - Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64$d filterable and/or sortable attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162451/magento-2-1-flat-catalog-module-has-a-limit-of-64d-filterable-and-or-sortable), It doesn't help me I need to use the flat indexing to speed up my site

How can I fix it? Is that a limit Error?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.1 - Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64$d filterable and/or sortable attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162451/magento-2-1-flat-catalog-module-has-a-limit-of-64d-filterable-and-or-sortable)

Comment: @Claims I had checked it didn't works can you suggest any other solution.